# Как изменить порядок расположения блоков?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Здравствуйте!
Как изменить порядок расположения блоков?

Использую `columns`, при этом порядок расположения - [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/7w9L4uoj/)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.columns {
  columns: 3;
}

.columns-item {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
}
.columns-item:nth-of-type(2n + 3){
  height: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div class="columns">
  <div class="columns-item">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="columns-item">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="columns-item">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="columns-item">
    4
  </div>
  <div class="columns-item">
    5
  </div>
  <div class="columns-item">
    6
  </div>
  <div class="columns-item">
    7
  </div>
  <div class="columns-item">
    8
  </div>
</div>
```

```
1 3 5
2 4 6
```

Но хотелось бы, чтобы порядок был таким

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

Comment: Columns для этого и придумано, как я понимаю, чтоб вертикально заполнять. Делайте через float:left и width:33.3%

Comment: @splash58 - при этом необходимо чтобы остался эффект masonry

Comment: тогда, не знаю :( сча спецы подскажут :)

Comment: пока спецы подтягиваются - посмотрите видео на  эту тему
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tSLH7i-2muI

Comment: гриды позволяют контролировать расположение блоков.